# Cannot delete article in Node/JavaScript app

Tags: node.js, ajax, mongodb

I want to delete my articles. The code should be working but I couldn't understand that it doesn't work. I have created a js file to send delete issue (with ajax)

This is my delete.js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.delete-article').on('click', function(e){
    $target = $(e.target);
    const id = $target.attr('data-id');
    $.ajax({
      type:'DELETE',
      url: '/metin/'+id,
      success: function(response){
        alert('Konu Siliniyor');
        window.location.href='/';
      },
      error: function(err){
        console.log(err);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

This is my app.js delete route:

```
app.delete('/metin/:id', function(req, res){
  let query = {_id: req.params.id};

  Metin.remove(query, function(err){
    if(err) {
      console.error(err);
    } else {
      res.send('Success');
    }
  });
});
```

This is my article.pug:

```
a.button.btn.btn-danger.delete-article(href='#', data-id=metin._id) Delete
```

Where do I missing a code? I couldn't find it. What can I check next?

Comment: What do you get as ajax response?

Comment: I done it. I forgrt to install jquery